# Compare Cells and exchange data

Tags: excel, vba

I am beginner in VBA-excel, and got stuck on one thing.
I tried to make my two columns to get in descending order every time
I change its data. Because I only had two columns, I thought I could just compare the cells and exchange them when the left one is smaller.

Below is the code I made, but doesn't work at all.
Could you tell me which parts I made mistakes?
Also, I would really appreciate if you have any methods to sort the data
whenever I update them.

Thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim temp As String
If Cells(Target.Row, 7).Value < Cells(Target.Row, 8).Value Then
temp = Cells(Target.Row, 8).Value
Cells(Target.Row, 8).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 7).Value
Cells(Target.Row, 7).Value = temp
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: For an event-triggered sub to work, it has to be placed in the correct location. Do you have this sub in the relevant sheet's code? A quick way to check, is to look at the left drop down box at top of the code module the sub is in. When your cursor is in that section of code, does that selection box say "Worksheet"?

Comment: Use the macro recorder to see what is the code to sort data by descending values. And then adapt it you your needs. If you get stuck, then you can ask here in SO

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
@Mistella I see I have my sub in the right place, when I checked the way you mentioned. Also, when I change the "Target.Row" into any constant number, I get the result I want. So I think the Target.Row is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I have also tried the recorder, but I couldn't find out the way to set up the macro for something to affect the other cells in the same row.

Comment: When I tested it in a sample workbook, it worked fine for me. If the value I put in column G was smaller than the value from column H, it switched the two values. **Note** The code will only look at values from columns G and H on the _one_ specific worksheet with the code. Another thought, do you have any protection on the sheets or workbook? Sometimes that can cause unexpected results.